# OpenERP, seeding Many2Many relationships with XML?

Tags: xml, database, many-to-many, odoo, seeding

I can't find any examples anywhere of seeding a `many-to-many` from `xml` data in `OpenERP`, does anyone know if this is possible, and if so how? I got `one2many` working with with the ref attribute, but nothing for `M2M`. No answer from the openerp help site either.

thanks!
Iain

Answer (score 5):

To learn how to specify data for many2many relations you may want to look at this document:

https://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html/#osv.osv.osv.write

For instance, the following gives a reference to a list of ids:

```
[(6, 0, [id1, id2, id3, ])]
```

For the use of many2many relations inside XML files i recommend the following reading:

https://doc.openerp.com/5.0/developer/5_16_data_serialization/xml_serialization/

Let take the example bellow for your situation. As you didn't give us an example of your code let suppose we have the following 2 objects in our new test_module:

```
import netsvc
import pooler
from osv import fields, osv

class group(osv.osv):
    _name = 'test_module.group'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char("Name", size=128,),
        }
group()

class user(osv.osv):
    _name = 'test_module.user'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char("Name", size=128,),
        'group_ids': fields.many2many('test_module.group',
                                      'test_module_user_group_rel',
                                      'user_id', 'group_id', 'Groups'),

user()
```

Now we can create a `demo.xml` file to populate the database in install and update time. This sample XML contains records for 4 groups and 2 users. Every user is related to two different groups:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="group_1" model="test_module.group">
            <field name="name" eval="'Group 1'"/>
        </record>
        <record id="group_2" model="test_module.group">
            <field name="name" eval="'Group 2'"/>
        </record>
        <record id="group_3" model="test_module.group">
            <field name="name" eval="'Group 3'"/>
        </record>
        <record id="group_4" model="test_module.group">
            <field name="name" eval="'Group 4'"/>
        </record>

        <record id="user_1" model="test_module.user">
            <field name="name" eval="'User 1'"/>
            <field name="group_ids"
                   eval="[(6, 0, [group_1, group_3, ])]"/>
        </record>
        <record id="user_2" model="test_module.user">
            <field name="name" eval="'User 2'"/>
            <field name="group_ids"
                   eval="[(6, 0, [group_2, group_3, ])]"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: What is the "6" and the "0" for?

Comment: They are described in the first link in my answer: https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html/#osv.osv.osv.write

Comment: Thanks, odoo documentation always feels so hard to understand, but I understand now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Andrei's answer - in Odoo 8 - if you are using xml ids from another module - you need to prefix the ids in the eval statement with `ref():`

```
eval="[(6, 0, [ref('module_name.xml_id'), ref('module_name.xml_id')])]"/>
```

Just found this out from examples of eval usage in the source code - and thought it might come in handy to someone.

I'm not sure if this also applies to xml ids in the same module as the eval - or whether it is specific to Odoo 8 though.